# Les enregistrements pour apprendre la prononciation des stations de métro de Paris

Tags: prononciation, transports

Dans le [métro de Paris](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9tro_de_Paris), il y a des annonces enregistrées indiquant le nom de chaque station.

Les annonces doivent avoir été mises en service ou enregistrées par la [Régie Autonome des Transports Parisiens (RATP)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9gie_autonome_des_transports_parisiens). La RATP c'est un [Établissement Public à caractère Industriel et Commercial (ou EPIC)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tablissement_public_%C3%A0_caract%C3%A8re_industriel_et_commercial). Donc, en tant que service public (non privatisé), je souhaiterais que la RATP rende ces enregistrements accessibles au public, par exemple avec une licence [Creative Commons](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons), afin d'aider les gens à apprendre à prononcer les noms des stations dans le métro parisien.

Est-ce que la RATP ou tout autre organisme officiel publie ces fichiers audio, et si oui, où ? Si non, quelles sont les autres bonnes façons d'apprendre comment les noms des stations de métro de Paris se prononcent ?

Comment: Le plus logique serait de [poser la question directement à la RATP](http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/r_29405/contacts/). Si vous n'obtenez pas de réponse [possibilité de s'adresser au médiateur](http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/vch_124175/mediateur/).

Comment: Sans garantir la fiabilité du service, je suggère Google Traduction, qui peut produire une synthèse vocale de ce qu'on y écrit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quelqu'un que je connais m'a envoyé une réponse utile (merci!):

> Depuis quelques années, la RATP a une démarche d'open data et publie
>   des données sur son site Internet. http://data.ratp.fr 
>   Malheureusement, le nom des stations ne fait pas partie des données
>   publiées. Il faudrait faire une demande directement à Open Data RATP
>   ici : http://data.ratp.fr/page/contact/

Si je reçois une réponse de la RATP, je vais résumer ici.

**EDIT - réponse de la RATP:**

> Ces fichiers ne sont pas disponible en open data. Toutefois, vous
>   trouverez une chaine SoundClound contenant des messages
>   https://soundcloud.com/ratp_officiel